# This perl oneliner that handles multiple lines doesn't work

Tags: regex, perl

I have this string as follows(which is the content of the test1.txt file):

```
one
1
</>
two
2
</>
```

I want it to become a new string like this:

```
one
1
</>
1
one
</>
two
2
</>
2
two
</>
```

I use the following perl oneliner to do just that.

```perl
perl -pi.bak -e 's#((.*)\n(.*)\n<\/>)#$1\n$3\n$2\n<\/>#g' "test1.txt"
```

but it did nothing to the test1.txt file.

Update:I like all three answers. They all provide some brilliantly useful information. I'm not sure in this situation which answer to accept…

Comment: `perl -p` di-sected: `$ perl -MO=Deparse -pe 1` -> `LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    '???'; 
} ...`, i.e. your one-liner uses line-based processing, but you want your regex to match multiple lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading a line at a time and matching against that one line, so your pattern can't possibly match.

The simple solution is to read the entire file as one line by using `-0777` (which sets `$/` to `undef`).

```
perl -i.bak -0777pe's#((.*)\n(.*)\n<\/>)#$1\n$3\n$2\n<\/>#g' test1.txt
```

Comment: Didn't know about the `-0` option. +1

Comment: Or perhaps it would be better not to read to whole file at once? And do something like`perl -pi.bak -e 'BEGIN{$/="</>\n"} s/(.*\n)(.*\n)(.*\n)\K/$2$1$3/' test1.txt`. Well, depends on the size of the file of course.

Answer (score 2):

The `-p` option assigns the input to the `$_` variable on a per-line basis, so your regex, which matches multiple lines, would not find a match. You should read the entire file before you try to apply the regex instead:

```
perl -i.bak -e 'undef $/;$_=<>;s#((.*)\n(.*)\n</>)#$1\n$3\n$2\n</>#g;print' "test1.txt"
```

Sample run in command line:

```
# perl -e 'undef $/;$_=<>;s#((.*)\n(.*)\n</>)#$1\n$3\n$2\n</>#g;print'<<EOF
> one
> 1
> </>
> two
> 2
> </>
> EOF
one
1
</>
1
one
</>
two
2
</>
2
two
</>
```

Comment: The output result seems not right: `1
</>
two
2
</>
2
two
</>1
</>
two
2
</>
2
two
</>`

Comment: Had a typo earlier with the `-p` option. Fixed it by removing it.

Comment: I run it again, this time the content of the file didn't change. But I changed the script a little to this: `perl -e 'undef $/;$_=<>;s#((.*)\n(.*)\n</>)#$1\n$3\n$2\n</>#g;print' "test1.txt" > "output.txt"` It works.

Answer (score 2):

Di-section of your one liner:

```perl
$ perl -MO=Deparse -pi.bak -e 's#((.*)\n(.*)\n<\/>)#$1\n$3\n$2\n<\/>#g' test.txt
BEGIN { $^I = ".bak"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    s[((.*)\n(.*)\n<\/>)][$1\n$3\n$2\n</>]g;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

i.e. your processing loop is line-based, whereas your regex wants to match multiple lines.

**NOTE:** my solutions use the more generic filter approach STDIN to STDOUT, not `-i.bak`.

You'll either have to slurp the file to memory and then apply the substitution...

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use open qw(:encoding(UTF-8) :std);

my $input;
{
    local $/;
    $input = <STDIN>;
}

$input =~ s,((.*)\n(.*)\n<\/>),$1\n$3\n$2\n<\/>,g;

print $input;

exit 0;
```

... or use section detection with bi-stable range operator in scalar context:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use open qw(:encoding(UTF-8) :std);

my @section;
while (<STDIN>) {
    if (/^\w+$/../^<\/>$/) {
        push(@section, $_);
    }

    print;

    # End of section reached
    if (/^<\/>$/) {
        # swivel lines around for desired output result...
        print @section[1, 0, 2];
        @section = ();
    }
}

exit 0;
```

Which approach is more appropriate depends on your real-life input file or additional processing requirements.

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl <dummy.txt
one
1
</>
1
one
</>
two
2
</>
2
two
</>
```

---

**UPDATE** if "no redirection" is an absolute requirement, you can replace the `<STDIN>` with `<>` to process the files on the command line, i.e.

```perl
my $input = <>;
```

or

```perl
while (<>) {
```

and on the command line:

```
$ perl -i.bak dummy.pl test1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your elaborate explanation, Stefan. I have tried the two approaches above, it seems the output is not the expected result though.

Comment: I had a typo in the 2nd solution which is fixed now. Both solutions gave me the result you wanted. Did you maybe forget the redirect on the command line (`<`)? Or is your absolute requirement that you can't use redirection?

Comment: I've added a section with no-redirection alternative, if that is the solution you prefer.

Comment: I just tried both approaches again:the first one works perfectly. a minor problem with the second one - the second '2' didn't start in a new line.

Comment: Then there must be something in your real file that didn't make it into your question, probably a copy & paste issue. I just tried both solutions on the same input text I copy & pasted from your question and they both generate the exact same output (according to `diff` on the ouput files).

Comment: Can it be that the last line in your input file doesn't have a line end? On my machine I have configured all editors to *always* make sure that the file is saved correctly with a line end after the last line (because I got tired of `git diff` complaining about `missing newline at end of file` :-)